# Javascript Button Hover works only once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement some button which displays list items on hover.

It works good however it stops working after the first hover then I need to keep refreshing the page for it to work again.

Please see the code below;

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); 
            
                    btn[0].addEventListener("click", function () { 
                        this.classList.toggle("active"); 
                        var content = this.nextElementSibling; 
                        if (content.style.display === "block") { 
                            content.style.display = "none"; 
                        } else { 
                            content.style.display = "block"; 
                        } 
                    });
```

Is there anyway I can make it work again and again without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This changes your code up a bit...*** Using Javascript, you can set a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listener for your elements nodelist, targeting the display style for the lists parent `ul` element.

Note the use of `querySelectorAll()`. This will create a node list of class identified in the method. Using a `forEach` method, it will call on the current value parameter set in the `forEach` function => **`button`**. You can then use the parentNode of the `event.target` and then get the `UL` as a child of the parent element. Then this will work on any amount of buttons and list items you want to have in your document, *provided the UL element is the second child of your parent element, otherwise you would need to tweak that part.*

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
btn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.children[1].style.display = "block";
  })
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.children[1].style.display = "none";
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

.list {
  display: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">Show the List</button>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="btn">Show the Second List</button>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list item 5</li>
    <li>list item 6</li>
    <li>list item 7</li>
    <li>list item 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <button class="btn">Show the Third List</button>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list item 9</li>
    <li>list item 10</li>
    <li>list item 11</li>
    <li>list item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say `hover` but show code using `click` I have two solutions for you:

This is very simple to do with CSS. `+` is the [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

#### Click

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); 
            
btn[0].addEventListener("click", function () { 
    this.classList.toggle("active"); 
});
```

```css
.collapsible + * {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible.active + * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Click Me!</button>
<p>
 Hello There!
<p>
```

#### Hover

```css
.collapsible + * {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible:hover + * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Hover Me!</button>
<p>
 Hello There!
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

for hover you need `mouseover` and `mouseout` event

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

btn[0].addEventListener("mouseover", btnHover);
btn[0].addEventListener("mouseout", btnHover);

function btnHover() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">hover</button>
<p style="display:none;">hello</p>
```